# How to automate MS Outlook

Tags: scripting, outlook, macros

I have to generate an email at end of the day (daily-status) which is templated. I have add tasks to different list and on the top, I have to have count of these tasks such as:

> X Tasks: 2 of 5
> Y Tasks: 3 of 5
>
> X Tasks:
>
> 1. X Task 1
> 2. X Task 2
>
> Y Tasks:
>
> 1. Y Task 1
> 2. Y Task 2
> 3. Y Task 3

I don't want write code in .NET etc. Is there anyway to script outlook to update numbers above when I change the list contents automatically. Or even better, if an input box can take input for each list contents and generate the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a Custom Outlook form that then generates an email.
I can all be done with VBScript inside the form.

I would sugesst a good place to start is to look at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=35

Marcus